# Stream oculus rift to android trough rtsp

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, oculus, virtual-reality

For an app I'm developing, I want to be able to visualize on an android device what an oculus rift is seeing in real time on a wlan network. (basically a commander/Game Master with a tablet and a player with the oculus rift)

The android device is able to display http, HLS and rtsp streams

*I've tried several solutions so far :*

**1 :**
Open broadcast software + nginx windows with RTMP module => HLS stream.
The delay is godawful (Around 10s average, minimum of 5-6s), but it works. It's not good enough for what i want though.

+ Works
- 10s delay

**2 :**
Recreation of the environment on the tablet. Basically the tablet is playing a low def version of the game, and data such as position and orientation are sent in real time to the tablet. The real time positioning and orientation works great. Instant feedback when the player look around. Sadly, some engine dependent issue arise after some time playing : Physics that is fps based, videos and sound playback rates that can't be changed with the android player.

+ Works great the first few seconds
- Fall completely out of sync after

**3 :**
What I'm trying to do now :
Stream as rtsp the output of the graphic card. Software such as Fraps or OBS can grab the output that I want. Then software such as LibAV/VLC or ffmpeg can stream any stream as rtsp. But neither can grab the output of a game correctly.
Surely there is some software/lib that allows me to grab a game screen and stream it ?

Thanks in advance if you have any input or ideas that might works.

Answer (score 1):

option 3 seems to be your best bet. the same way twitch uses the gpu to capture the frames, you can do so without a performance lost, and then stream it to the device of your choosing. This is also similar to how in home streaming for steam works iirc